# Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string return mysql average

Tags: php, mysqli

Can someone explain how I would output the result of the sql below? currently getting 'Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string'.

```
$sql = ("SELECT AVG(ab_satisfactionScore) AS AverageSatisfactionScore
     FROM tbl_appointmentsbooked;");

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

echo ($result);
```

Comment: When you're doing an echo on an object it looks for a magic method called `__toString()`, if it doesn't find that method it will throw an error. That's what's happening here. With that said, you need to get the results from the query, as it stands it returns an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error because you are echoing an object, so try like this,

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo $res['AverageSatisfactionScore'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of `mysqli_fetch_*()` functions (or in OOP style: `$result->fetch_*()`) to retrieve the results from the mysqli_results object ($results).

See [mysqli_result documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) on the various methods and their uses.

Answer (score -1):

because you try to use `echo` to print object, and it used to print string only, you should use:

```
print_f($result);
```

instead of

```
echo ($result);
```

Comment: $result is an object representing the returned resultset.